# Copy Value and Format from a set of cells from multiple worksheet to a final "Summary" Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, format, cell

I would like to copy all data filled cells (value as well as the format) from a specific column (e.g. Column C) from multiple sheets (Sheet1, Sheet 2, Sheet N) to a worksheet "Summary" (Column C) in a loop. I am using the below VBA code which currently only copies the value but not the format. Please suggest a solution.

I am using the below VBA code which currently only copies the value but not the format.

```vb
Sub AuthorityCitation()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Loop through worksheets, put the values in column C into arr array
Dim arr(1 To 10000), cnt As Integer, i As Integer, ws As Worksheet, RFormat As Range
cnt = 0
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            cnt = cnt + 1
            arr(cnt) = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
        
       Next i
   End If
Next ws

'Loop through arr array, populate value into Summary sheet, column C
For i = 1 To cnt
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "C") = arr(i)
    
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to copy values and formats you need to copy/paste each cell - you can't use an array.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Tim. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### Stack Columns Vertically in a Summary Worksheet

```vb
Sub AuthorityCitation()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Summary")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("C2")
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sws In Worksheets
        If Not sws Is dws Then
            Set srg = sws.Range("C2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            srg.Copy dfCell
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count)
       End If
    Next sws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Columns imported to worksheet Summary.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like magic!! Thanks a lot....